# Android Studio - Why does my recycler-view get stuck without letting me scrolling to its bottom?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, slide

**Description**

I am using a recycler view that has more items inside than screen´s height, so to see them we should scroll down. The problem is that I can only scroll some *dps* down (like 10 or 20 dps).

**What do I need?**

I need to scroll to it´s bottom in order to see **all** recycler´s views.

**My design is private so I am going to show you a graphic:**

[image]

The blue box is my recycler view. It has ten views loaded, but we can only see two and a half. I can slide so that I can see "Daddy Yankee" full name, but not more than that.

**My fragment XML code (in which I have my recycler)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#8d6e63"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_back_negro"
        android:tint="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_lobby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:text="Lobby"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15.5sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgbt_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_names"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="(10) names"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint_bar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_barra0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_names"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_names"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_barra0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**What can I do to slide my recycler to the bottom to be able to see all the other views?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this constraint on your `id/recycler_names`:

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

and then set `layout_height` to `0dp` (match constraint).